# Where do I find those types in .h file

Tags: c

In a .h file there's no includes of other .h files

then I see uint8_t, int16_t, spin lock_t, atomic_t, ssize_t,_be32, _be16, 
the primitives like char, unsigned long, struct are understood by compilers, but what about those one ends with _t?  where are they defined?

I check linux/kernel.h, i don't see them also.

Comment: google, google, google, ...

Comment: Do you have any code examples? What are you trying to accomplish? Have you tried anything? What are your results?

Comment: `<stdint.h>` for the standard c types.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux kernel and Linux kernel modules, they are all defined in:

```
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/types.h
```